# Layout doesn't show first item of View

Tags: java, android, xml, view, swipe

I download pictures and names from a parse database and create a cardstack. Every view has a name and a picture, but I don't see the first picture of my view (position 0) until I use my swipe left or swipe right button (then I see it swiping away), the nameAgeLabel works fine.

Do you have any ideas how I can fix it? Nothing should overlap it, I checked again and again, but maybe i overlooked something special regarding position 0 in my adapter. The data should also be fine, otherwise the nameAgeLabel wouldn't work.

I can delete some of the Layouts in my content.xml, but that won't help either.

Edit: I now get an information in my log ONLY for my first view:

```
W/View: requestLayout() 
improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView....app:id/nameAgeLabel} during 
layout: running second layout pass
```

SwipeDeckAdapter:

```
public class SwipeDeckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LinkedList<String> data;
private Context context;
private LinkedList<String> userIds;
private Hashtable<String,String> userNames;
private Hashtable<String,String> userHashtags;
private Hashtable<String,Bitmap> userImages;
private Hashtable<String,ArrayList<String>> userAccepted;
private TextView nameAgeLabel;

public SwipeDeckAdapter(LinkedList<String> data, Context context, LinkedList<String> userIds, Hashtable<String,String> userNames, Hashtable<String,String> userHashtags, Hashtable<String,Bitmap> userImages, Hashtable<String,ArrayList<String>> userAccepted, TextView nameAgeLabel) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    this.userIds = userIds;
    this.userNames = userNames;
    this.userHashtags = userHashtags;
    this.userImages = userImages;
    this.userAccepted = userAccepted;
    this.nameAgeLabel = nameAgeLabel;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}




@Override
public View getView(final int position, View View, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d("position:", String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d("laenge user id", String.valueOf(userIds.size()));

    final String currentUserId = userIds.get(position);

    View v = View;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_single_mode_vc, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.offer_image);
    Bitmap image;
    try {
        image = userImages.get(currentUserId);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    } catch (IOError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("info", userNames.toString());
    Log.d("info", userNames.get(currentUserId));
    nameAgeLabel.setText(userNames.get(userIds.get(position)));
    return v;
}
```

I invoke it in another class like this:

```
//next line in my onCreate
cardStack = (SwipeDeck) findViewById(R.id.swipe_deck);

//back in my method
adapter= new SwipeDeckAdapter(data, getApplicationContext(), userIds, userNames, userHashtags, userImages, userAccepted,nameAgeLabel);
                            // e.printStackTrace();
                            if(cardStack != null){
                                cardStack.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
```

content_single_mode_vc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="25dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offer_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_single_mode_vc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.layouts.SwipeFrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:swipedeck="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white">

<com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.SwipeDeck
    android:id="@+id/swipe_deck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    swipedeck:max_visible="1"
    swipedeck:card_spacing="15dp"
    swipedeck:swipe_enabled="true"
    swipedeck:render_above="true">

</com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.SwipeDeck>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="@drawable/check"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/nameAgeLabel"
    android:background="@color/separator"
   />
 </com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.layouts.SwipeFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using swipedeck:max_visible="1" in the layout of the DeckSwipe that's why it is a bug in the library. Try to increase the max_visible to 2 or 3 and it will work fine for you.

If you need to show only one card you can modify the SwipeDeck.java in the library and replace the setAdapter function as below:

```
public void setAdapter(final Adapter adapter) 
{
        if (adapter == null)
            return;

        if (this.mAdapter != null) {
            this.mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
        mHasStableIds = adapter.hasStableIds();
        mAdapter = adapter;
        .
        .
        .
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        if (deck.size() > 0)
            addNextView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }
```